# ubuntu import aiohttp ImportError: No module named 'aiohttp'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I tried to install AIoHTTP with PIP and PIp3 and successed doing it, but when I ran with command python3 scripts/init_social_graph.py, the following error still occurred

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/init_social_graph.py", line 1, in <module>
    import aiohttp
ImportError: No module named 'aiohttp'
```

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import sys
```

Comment: Run `python3 -m pip list` - can you see your installed modules? Run `which python3` - are you using this version when launching your script?

Answer (score 0):

Try run your script with virtual environvent:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv --python=python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install aiohttp
python scripts/init_social_graph.py
```

> virtualenv --python=python3 env

this will create folder "env" with python3 virtual environment

If you use Windows just try uninstall and install the actual version of Python